# Recognize columns with quotes as character/categorical

Tags: r

I've a csv where some columns are integers between quotes: 
`"14", "3", "6", "3"` and other columns are integers without quotes: `3, 5, 0, 2`

Is there a way to automatically detect columns with integers between quotes as character or categorical and columns with integers without quotes as integers when I import a csv to `R`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `quote = ""` to the `read.csv` statement.  The `as.is=TRUE` ensures that character rather than factor is used for the quoted columns.   To avoid quotes in the headings we set the `col.names` to the names of a second read version in which `quotes=""` is not used.  Omit the last line marked ## if you want the quotes to be part of the data.

```
Lines <- '"a","b"\n"1",1'
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, quote = "", as.is = TRUE, 
         col.names = names(read.csv(text = Lines, nrow = 1)))
DF[] <- lapply(DF, function(x) if (inherits(x, "character")) gsub('"', '', x) else x) ##
```

giving:

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr "1"
 $ b: int 1
```

Comment: It works when I execute read.csv('test.csv', quote = "") but it does something weird on the columns names since they were also between quotes. (e.g with this file https://ufile.io/exb08).

Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: Have expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use package `readr`:

```
> readr::read_csv("test.txt", col_types = "ci")
# A tibble: 1 × 2
    `2`   `3`
  <chr> <int>
    1    14
```